# Conversion of C# code to Delphi code (if condition)

Tags: c#, delphi

I'm converting a C# project to Delphi and am struggling with this C# code:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(myItem.mySubItem?.Content) && (myItem.Quantity == 0) && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(myItem.Description)))
{
  continue;
}
```

From my understanding the Delphi code should look like this:

```
if assigned(myItem.mySubItem) and (length(trim(myItem.mySubItem.Content)) > 0) and (myItem.Quantity = 0) and (length(trim(myItem.Description)) = 0) then begin
    Continue;
end;
```

But I'm not 100% sure, because logically it doesn't make sense. That's another story though. My question is: is my Delphi code a correct conversion of the quoted C# code?

In case it's wrong, what would be the correct code?

Comment: did it do what you wanted when you compiled it?? thats the best test]

Comment: Just very curious: Why converting to a, say, more 'niche' product?

Comment: Pretty hard for us to offer advice without knowing what type anything is. Why don't you strip this down to what you don't understand? Presumably you know what `&&` is in C# and what `and` is in Delphi. So remove that from the question. Perhaps your question is about `String.IsNullOrEmpty`. And have you considered reading documentation to find the answers?

Comment: @BigFinder: It does compile, but it's a small piece of a foreign project. I can't compile that foreign project, so can't say for sure, what is the supposed outcome. So I've just asked about the code part in question.

Comment: @Udontknow: my main project is a Delphi project and I'm trying to "integrate" the C# project into it.

Comment: Why would you need to compile anything? That would never prove anything anyway, not unless you could test it against sufficient inputs to cover all possible eventualities. Why are you so set against gaining understanding?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan myItem and mySubItem are two classes. "Content" and "Description" are two string properties, "Quantity" is a decimal / double property. It's about the whole if condition and it's parts. "!" at the beginning, "?" after mySubItem and String.IsNullOrEmpty too...

Comment: I'm set against gaining understanding? I've tried to find informations and made a Delphi code according to it and just asked for confirmation and possible corrections. Why are you making such a big deal of it?

Comment: Because you don't seem to want to learn anything. You could readily read documentation for the C# language, and be able to understand the C# code yourself. Instead you look for a yes/no answer as to whether or not your translation is correct. Which you are likely to do again and again as you continue with this task. We are not a translation service. You could work this out for yourself more effectively that have us give a yes/no. You'd then be confident that you got it right. And finally, you'd have more knowledge and be a better programmer.

Comment: Furthermore, you've missed a great deal of information from the question, you've not made any attempt in the question to boil it down to the key point, you've included more code than necessary. All in all, I judge that you aren't trying hard enough. No doubt you won't like that opinion, people seldom do. But really, do you believe that you have not got the ability to understand this C# code? Really?!

Comment: C# strings can be null, which was a huge bummer in designing the language. That's why method String.IsNullOrEmpty exists. Delphi strings can't be null, so you can simply check with s <> ""

Answer (score 1):

You are trimming the delphi strings before checking against a length of 0. In c#, a string containing only spaces is not 'NullOrEmpty'.